# Role of framework in between Extension and App in ios

Tags: ios, frameworks

I'm bit confused about the concepts of Extension in ios. After going through some tutorials I still have doubt how an app and an extension in ios communicate each other, does this has to do anything with Framework. If Yes, why we are adding Frameworks...

Hoping for a response, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- App extensions are not stand alone apps. They are providing extended functionality of the app (which can be accessed from main app, called the host app) that is meant to be efficient and focused towards a single task.
- For example, Today widget  in iPhone is an extension. We can create a today widget for an iOS app which is an extension of the existing iOS app. For example, let us consider an app which shows current weather in detail. Then you can create an extension for this app, to show only current temperature without much detail in a widget.
- The extension uses the data which is shared between both the main app and the extension. Embedded framework is a technique to share same code between two targets. You can share data using NSUserdefaults and app group concept.

Comment: Why did you accept the answer and again un accept it.